# Monitor arguments of call to dylib in Macos

Tags: macos, dylib

I'd like something similar to [apimonitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) but for Macos. Is there something like this already? Thank you. I'd like to be able to know the arguments used by an application when calling dylib functions.

Comment: Rather than referring to apimonitor, explain you want to do independent of what other tools do. What dylib(s) are you interested in? What functions? Are you attempting to examine the behavior of your own app or some other app? Why do you want to know the arguments the app is using and what do you hope to do with that information? (That may be useful to us to recommend possible alternative approaches, entirely.)

Comment: I'd like to examine the calls from a third party application in order to examine the arguments sent to a function in the dylib file. Since I don't have access to the source code, this comes down to reverse engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

Have you considered just attaching a debugger (i.e. `lldb`) to the app, setting a breakpoint on the function of interest, and observing the arguments? You could set the breakpoint to automaticaly print the arguments and then continue.

You can use the `pid` provider of DTrace. Much of DTrace is disabled by System Integrity Protection (SIP). I don't recall if the `pid` provider is or not. If it's disabled, you can enable it when booted to Recovery Mode using the `csrutil` command (`csrutil enable --without dtrace`).

Anyway, the command to use the `pid` provider is:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'pid$target:library pattern:function pattern:entry { actions }' -p <PID of target>
```

The patterns are file-glob-style, using `*` to match any characters and `?` to match a single character.

An action can be something like `ustack();` to dump the user stack, `printf("%x\n", arg0);` to print the first argument, etc. See a DTrace manual for more.

Finally, you can use the `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment variable to inject a library of your own. That library, in turn, can use [dyld symbol interposing](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-519.2.2/include/mach-o/dyld-interposing.h.auto.html) to install your own version of a given function or functions, which can do whatever you want. It can call through to the original and thus act as a wrapper.

Note that SIP can also interfere with passing `DYLD_*` environment variables through to the executable.